How to pass on the chopped details from URL in Django?
I have a project with the following urls.py.
urlpatterns = [
    path('category*/', include('student.urls')) // * could be replaced by a number
]

In that project I then have an application student whose urls.py looks like this:
urlpatterns = [
    path('all/', views.all, name='all')
]

So lets say when I type in the URL category1/all/ I get the list of all Category 1 students, but when I do category2/all/ I should be able to get the list of all Category 2 students. So by the time I reach all/ I have lost for which category I want to retrieve the list of all students.  How can I still know in my students application which category students data should be retrieved?

You can work with a parameter:
urlpatterns = [
    path('category<int:cat>/', include('student.urls')),
]
then the view all takes that parameter:
def all(request, cat):
    # …
    pass
where cat is thus an int depending on the number in the path.

Should work with a Class Based View as well...
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    cat = kwargs.get("cat", 0)


Thank you! The problem was that I just had parameters in the URL but not explicitly passing them as method arguments. This helped.
